# pd.concat not stacking columns with same names

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm in awe that this isn't working because I've done this a hundred times. I want to stack two dataframes vertically and pandas is creating duplicate columns and refusing to put the data in the right columns.

df1 looks like this:

[image]

df2 looks like this:

[image]

then I run this:

```
frames = [df1,df2]
final = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index = True, axis = 0)
final
```

and get 6 columns instead of 3 like this:

[image]

I have no idea why two dataframes with identical column names and data types would not simply stack on top of each other. Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

update:

Big Thanks to @Naveed there was trailing whitespace in one of the dataframe's columns.

Here is the final fix:

```
df2.columns = [x.strip() for x in df2.columns]
frames = [df1,df2]
final = pd.concat(frames,ignore_index = True, axis = 0)
final
```

Comment: Are your columns secretly named something a little different? Can you run `set(df1.columns.values) ^ set(df2.columns.values)` and see if it's an empty set or if something remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

check the column names, there might be white spaces that results in mis-alignment of column after the concat.

```
display(df1.columns, df2.columns)
```

```
#  make axis=0 and remove ignore_index

final = pd.concat(frames,   axis = 0)
final
```

Comment: see update for what it looks like when axis =1 @Naveed

Comment: don't ignore index , remove that attribute. check the reference https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html?highlight=concat#pandas.concat

Comment: results in the same when I take that out too.

Comment: my apologies. if you post the data as a code (preferably) or text, it allows to reproduce it and share the result. Your original code was correct, it should be axis=0. However, it appears that the column names has some difference, might be whitespace (just guessing here). Can you check and compare the columns names by reviewing output from display(df1.columns, df2,columns). columns names will be in quote, that tells you if there are any whitespaces

Comment: You were right! Ran this before running and it fixed it.
```explorium_original_mappings.columns = [x.strip() for x in explorium_original_mappings.columns]```
Thank you so much I was losing my mind over here. I didn't even know columns could have whitespace!

Comment: so happy that it resolved the issue. I felt bad to have made you repeatedly try different suggestion. I update the solution and make it axis=0

Comment: No problem that was a sneaky error. Now I know to look for that! Thank you again!